# Proper way to remove unused linked Group data-blocks

Tags: python, data-blocks

In the outliner i have a local library called "Current File" and a linked library called "//foo.blend". Is this the proper way to remove all unused group-datablock-links from the "//foo.blend"-library?

```
import bpy

groups = bpy.data.groups
for group in groups:
    if group.library and group.library.filepath == "//foo.blend":
        if group.users == 1 and len(group.users_dupli_group) == 0: # EDIT
            group.user_clear()
            groups.remove(group)  # <- crash warning, don't use this part of the example.
```

Comment: Using user_clear() can be dangerous, you should always try to get user count to 0 by clearing references that exist, see [user_clear()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/bpy.types.ID.html?highlight=user_clear#bpy.types.ID.user_clear)

Comment: @CoDEmanX, `user_clear()` is safe, but `user_clear()` followed by `remove()` can crash if the group was used anywhere. Best use `user_clear()` then save and reload.

Comment: but with `len(group.users_dupli_group) == 0` added, it should be save?

Comment: @ni-ko-o-kin, no, because there are group users that are not dupli-groups (particle-systems for example).

Answer (score 5):

Groups are intentionally **not** garbage collected, (so they have to be removed manually). Only a few kinds of data-blocks behave this way, Scene's are another example.

As a user, you can select them in the outliner and unlink them, but there is no way to remove single user groups other then to script this as you have done.

For details see the [reference manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html#users-garbage-collection).

Answer (score 0):

Add an object, just something simple like a cube, add that cube to the group you want to remove. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, and choose the group you want to remove. Then close the scene, and re-open it. That group will be gone!

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to add a cube.